# Incorrect Syntax near <db name>. Expecting Audit_Specification, Current, Encryption_Key, ID or Quoted_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, sql-server-2016

Currently have a database with the name: 3011105818V2
I'm trying to alter the storage location and for some reason, SQL doesn't like the "V2" ending part of the database name...

```
ALTER DATABASE 3011105818V2
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = 3011105818V2,   
              FILENAME = 'Z:\Databases\3011105818V2.mdf');
```

[editor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3c7t.png)

I can't change the name of the DB so how do I go about getting it to recognize the true DB name?

Comment: Try putting brackets around it [3011105818V2]

Comment: Son of a ... that was all it needed.  Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Always tag it. No single vendor (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2) owns the SQL language.